# Windows 10 PC periodically pops-up a command prompt window but it closes before I can see it

Tags: windows-10, command-line, virus, popups

I've been struggling with this for some time now. Essentially, every 20-30 seconds a cmd window opens and immediately closes. I'm afraid my computer might be infected with something. I've tried using Process Monitor to capture the process and I'm 90% sure I have found the culprit.

[possible bad process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZX4x.png)

The full command line text is:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AddInProcess.exe -pool etc.2miners.com:1010 -wal 0x0EfF5C8f6461bdda77552D51CBea327740426bb0.cr1 -pass x -cdm 0 -mi 12 -log 0 -coin etc`

It seems to be reaching out to etc.2miners.com:1010 which is some sort of Ethereum mining pool? How can I figure out what's calling this and how to stop it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look in Programs and Features to uninstall it.  Run a full scan with Windows Defender.  Then restart

Comment: What am I uninstalling?

Comment: To see if there is a program rogue or otherwise responsible for this process.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary. Also, I'm running a scan currently with Virus and Threat Protection but it's just been sitting there. Hasn't scanned a single file in 10 minutes.

Comment: If Windows Defender hangs then you could well have a bad virus. Back  up your computer (data, documents, email and so on) and reinstall Windows.

Comment: https://etc.2miners.com/

Comment: If you cannot get rid of that, then reinstall as I showed in my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I've been struggling with this for some time now. Essentially, every
> 20-30 seconds a cmd window opens and immediately closes. I'm afraid my
> computer might be infected with something. I've tried using Process
> Monitor to capture the process and I'm 90% sure I have found the
> culprit.

I suggested you run Windows Defender.

In a summary of the comments, you say Windows Defender has hung for an abnormally long time.

This is evidence of a bad virus.

Back up Windows (data, documents, favorites, email and so on).

Then reinstall Windows and recover your data.

Comment: Ok I will try this.